# posts and comments relationship in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, comments, one-to-many, posts

I would like to create posts and comments for users to write and show them on the index page.

I have two tables in my database (**different syntax ofc**):

```
 NEWS
  id int (100) AUTO_INCREMENT
  title varchar (40) NOT NULL
  content varchar (40) NOT NULL

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

and

```
 COMMENTS
  id int (100) AUTO_INCREMENT
  vesti_id int (100) NOT NULL
  sadrzaj varchar (300) NOT NULL

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (vesti_id) REFERENCES vesti (id)
```

and my php code:

```
    <?php


$Komentar = "";

$errors = array();


 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'poslednji');

if (!$db){

echo ("Neuspela konekcija!");

}


if (isset($_POST['ostavikomentar'])) {   //button for posting a comment

 $Komentar = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['komentarpolje']); 

// ['komentarpolje'] is a name of a textarea 



 if (empty($Komentar)) {array_push($errors, "Niste napisali komentar");}



 if (count($errors) == 0) {
 $query = "INSERT INTO komentari (vesti_id, sadrzaj)
          VALUES ('I HOPE SOME1 WILL HELP ME WITH THIS PART', '$Komentar')";
  mysqli_query($db, $query);



    array_push($errors, "Uspesno ste ostavili komentar!");
  //header( "refresh:1;url=index.php" );

  }
}   


?>
```

I can figure out how to display them, but...

I understand the logic that every comments will show for THEIR posts with the help of an **foreign key**.

Also I can understand that this is **One-to-Many** relationship (because one post can have multiple comments, but one comment can't have multiple posts).

How should I write my **query**? And how can I generate that every comment goes to his designed post?

Comment: "vesti" is "news"? (it's confusing now what is what)

Comment: well, basicly it would be `"INSERT INTO komentari (vesti_id, sadrzaj)
          VALUES ($vesti_id, '$Komentar')"` - but you need to figure out where that `$vesti_id` comes from. It should be sent with the form (as a hidden input?).

Comment: __BUT__ please start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)! Your code is unsecure.

Comment: Yes, vesti is news. I understand that I should put $vesti_id as a value, but how can I get the right id from news to put in variable $vesti_id?

Comment: Somewhere in your form to comment you'd need a hidden input that sends the current $vesti_id along with the comment.